# mtl file missing map_kd

Tags: blender, mtl-file

I'm using blender to export an obj file. The obj file works fine to me, however, the mtl file doesn't have map_kd  for most materials.[image]

But there is an exception thought, only this one have map_kd:

[image]

And here is what it looks like in my Blender:

[image]

Comment: Cycles uses node based materials that don't export to other apps. Use blender internal to get materials that export.

Comment: If you prefer working in Cycles, you actually can. Mostly. You need to switch to Blender Internal long enough to create and assign the texture, but once that's done you can switch back.